# Save values while inside a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, save

So I have the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfTickets; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your age or if you are a student enter -1");
        int age = input.nextInt();

        if ((age < 10) && (age > 0)) 
        {
            cost = (cost / 4);
        } 
        else if ((age < 16) && (age >= 10)) 
        {
            cost = (cost / 2);
        } 
        else if (age > 60) 
        {
            cost = (cost / 2.5);
        }
        else if (age == -1)
        {
            cost = (cost / (4/3));
        }
        System.out.println(cost);
        }
```

the problem is say that initially the cost is £10 and the user enters an age of 12 I want the value of £5 to be saved as say int ticketCost1 before continuing the for loop but starting with 10 again.
In essence i want to at the end of the loop have all the costs of the tickets with the individual discounts applied and to be then able to dd them all together and have a final cost.

P.S. I intend to add more so that for every child i.e. age 0 to 10 then they go free with anyone over the age of 16.

In java.

Comment: You need something to hold that data for you, `public class TicketHelper{ int age; float cost; /* some other things */ }`  and `List<TicketHelper>`

Comment: Sorry you will hate me for this but the above code is about as advanced as i get so you will have to spoon feed me haha. Could you just explain to me in the simplest possible terms.

Comment: Basically add() to an ArrayList of TicketHelper items.  Then after the loop you have logic to do the discounts. Pass one counts the number of people older than 16.  Pass 2 will remove tickets for under 10 based on number of adults.  Pass 3 will add it all up.  If you are using java8 you can use the the streaming functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new double, for now lets call it sum. Now instead of writing:

```
 cost = (cost/whatever);
```

do this:

```
sum+= (cost/whatever);
```

now you save all them in 1 number summed, and cost stays as 10; while all the discounts are applied. Just make sure you initialize sum to 0 OUTSIDE and before the for loop

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a group of people of varying ages, and you want to find the total cost of all the tickets purchased by the group. You can have two lists, then: one to store the ages, and one to store the ticket costs. The cost of the group will be the total cost stored in the second list.

```
static final TICKET_PRICE = 10;

int getTotalCost(List<Integer> ages) { // populated list of ages
    List<Integer> costs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i : ages)
        costs.add(getTicketPrice(int age));
    int totalCost = 0;
    for (int curr_cost : costs)
        totalCost += curr_cost;
    return totalCost;
}

int getTicketPrice(int age) {
    int price;
    if (age > 60) price = TICKET_PRICE/2.5;
    ... // all the other conditions, e.g. for students, children under 10, etc.
    else price = TICKET_PRICE; // if no special condition applies
    return price;
}
```

For the more complicated conditions (e.g. a child under 10 goes free with another person over the age of 16), it's best if you have a separate method to compute the total cost. Keep in mind that as you increase these conditions that depend not just on the individual, but on the age-distribution of the whole group, the optimal cost computation will start to resemble quite a complex problem in and of itself.